# Export many Html tables to an Exceldocument

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, csv, export-to-excel

I want to export many html tables to an excel document, I've searched a lot but the only solution I found was how to export one table to excel document. what I need is to have many worksheets in one document. The extraction from server side does not resolve my problem, because I have to do some treatment with javascript.

Comment: but Excel does the width already and you can't have JavaScript doing width's in Excel

Comment: sorry I edit my question (I have to do some treatment like filtring data or sorting)

Comment: but filtering data can also be done server-side right? next to that, generating a CSV file is pretty easy in JavaScript

Comment: I already generate excel file from one table (jquery) but now I want to generate multi-sheets from multi-tables in the same document. I don't know If I was clear.

Comment: What about this [ExcelBuilder](http://excelbuilderjs.com/) ?

Comment: I tried to used it, but it's not well documented.

Comment: how can I do filtering data server-side ? I have many large tables, and I want to do filtering, sorting then exporting to excel format.